# Javascript for loop not repeating strings

Tags: javascript

very new to Javascript here, and I think I'm having a logic issue. So basically for class I'm building a hangman game, and I am having trouble with double letters. for instance if the word is food, when I enter an "O" it will pass through the for loop, hit that first O, push it to the screen, and stop dead in its tracks. I can do whatever I want to that first "O" but a second one or any other repeated letter gets ignored. Now the alert I wrote directly under the start of the for() loop, will successfully print both "O's", as will logging it to the console, or even flat out writing document.write(splitWord[m]);

So to me, I think it has to be my if statement. I could be 100% wrong on this, but I assume that the if statement tells it to see the first "O", do what's in the bracket, and then move on to the next letter skipping any doubles. If I am right about this, what would be a better option to keep the loop going, so both "O's" would be filled. And if I am completely wrong, what would be a better course of action to accomplish this task. Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```js
var remainingLetters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];


var removedLetters =[];
var wordList = ["django", "the#good#the#bad#and#the#ugly", "a#fistful#of#dollars","for#a#few#dollars#more","once#upon#a#time#in#the#west","the#wild#bunch","pale#rider"];
var titleList =["django", "The Good The Bad And The Ugly", "A Fistful of Dollars", "For a few Dollars More", "Once Upon a Time in the West", "The Wild Bunch", "Pale Rider"];
var songList =["Jango", "The Good The Bad And The Ugly", "Fistful of Dollars", "For a few Dollars More", "Once Upon a Time in the West", "The Wild Bunch", "Pale Rider"]



var selectedWord;
console.log(selectedWord);

var livesRemaining = 12;
var score = 0;
var wordWorth = 0;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var gameOn = false;

function chooseAWord(){
 selectedWord = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
 console.log(selectedWord);
}

function printWord(){
  document.getElementById("wordDisplayer").innerHTML = selectedWord;
}


function buildTiles(){ 
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it some content 
  var splitWord = selectedWord.split("");
  for(i = 0; i < splitWord.length; i++){
   if (splitWord[i] != '#'){
     // var newTile = document.createElement("div"); 
    //var newContent = document.createTextNode(""); 
      //newTile.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.

  document.getElementById("wordTiles").innerHTML += '<div class="tileStyle" id="' + splitWord[i] + '"></div>';

   wordWorth++;
   


    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
    //var currentDiv = document.getElementById("wordTiles");  
     //currentDiv.appendChild(newTile, currentDiv);
   
    // newTile.setAttribute("class", "tileStyle");
     }else if(splitWord[i] == '#'){
      var blankTile = document.createElement("div"); 
      var spaceContent = document.createTextNode("");
      blankTile.appendChild(spaceContent);

      document.getElementById("wordTiles").innerHTML += '<div class="blankStyle" id="' + splitWord[i] + '"></div>';
     }
    }
}


function clearTiles(){
 var myNode = document.getElementById("wordTiles");
 while (myNode.firstChild) {
     myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
 }

}

function refreshAlphabet(){
 remainingLetters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
 displayAvailableLetters();
}


function keyPressed(){
 checkPlayerChoiceNew();
}

var playerGuess = document.onkeyup = function myKeyDown(event){
 playerGuess = event.key;
 if(gameOn==true){
  keyPressed();
 }else{

 }
}




function checkPlayerGuess(){
 document.getElementById("isThisWorking").innerHTML = playerGuess;

}




// function myFunction() {
//    var str = "Tha bast things in lifa ara free";
//    var patt = new RegExp(playerGuess);
 //   var res = patt.test(selectedWord.toLowerCase());
//    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
//}


function displayAvailableLetters(){
 document.getElementById("lettersStillAvailable").innerHTML = remainingLetters;
 console.log(remainingLetters);
 
}

function displayRemovedLetters(){
 document.getElementById("lettersUsed").innerHTML = removedLetters;
}


function updateScore(){
 document.getElementById("scoreTotal").innerHTML = score;
}

function updateWins(){
 document.getElementById("winTotals").innerHTML = wins;
}
function updateLosses(){
 document.getElementById("lossTotals").innerHTML = losses;
}

function checkScore(){
 if(score == selectedWord.length && livesRemaining > 0){
  document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "WINNER! Congratulations!!!";
  wins++;
  updateWins();
  gameOn=false;
 }else if (livesRemaining == 0){
  livesRemaining == -1;
  document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "You have failed!";
  losses++;
  updateLosses();
  gameOn=false;
 }else{
  document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "Good Luck!";
 }
}

function checkPlayerChoiceNew(){
 var splitWord = selectedWord.split("");
 var choice = new RegExp(playerGuess);
 var compareWord = choice.test(selectedWord.toLowerCase());
 var compareAlphabet = choice.test(remainingLetters);
 var compareRemovedList = choice.test(removedLetters);
 
 for (m = 0; m < splitWord.length; m++){
  //alert(splitWord[m]);
  if(playerGuess == splitWord[m]){
   document.getElementById(splitWord[m]).innerHTML = playerGuess;
 
  }
 }
}
//check playerGuess against selectedWord
function checkPlayerChoice(){
 var choice = new RegExp(playerGuess);
 var compareWord = choice.test(selectedWord.toLowerCase());
 var compareAlphabet = choice.test(remainingLetters);
 var compareRemovedList = choice.test(removedLetters);

 if(compareWord == true && compareAlphabet == true ){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = playerGuess;
  
  remainingLetters.splice(remainingLetters.indexOf(playerGuess),1);
  displayAvailableLetters();
  displayRemovedLetters();
  score++;
  updateScore();
  checkScore();
 }else if(compareWord == true && compareAlphabet == false){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Already tried that one";
 }else if(compareWord == false && compareAlphabet == true){
  livesRemaining--;
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = livesRemaining;
  removedLetters.push(playerGuess.toLowerCase());
  remainingLetters.splice(remainingLetters.indexOf(playerGuess),1);
  updateScore();
  checkScore();
  displayAvailableLetters();
  displayRemovedLetters();
 }else if (compareWord == false && compareAlphabet == false && compareRemovedList == true){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Already tried that one ;)";
 }else if (compareWord == false && compareAlphabet == false && compareRemovedList == true){

 }else{
  /*livesRemaining--;
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = livesRemaining;
  removedLetters.push(playerGuess.toLowerCase());
  updateScore();
  checkScore();
  displayAvailableLetters();
  displayRemovedLetters();*/
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Not a Valid Key";
 }
}





//document.onkeyup = function myKeyDown(event){
// playerGuess = event.key;
 
//}

//start / Restart the game
function resetGame() {
 livesRemaining = 12;
 score =0;
 wordWorth = 0;
 clearTiles();
 document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = livesRemaining;
 chooseAWord();
 printWord();
 buildTiles();
 refreshAlphabet();
 gameOn=true;
}
```

```css
.tileStyle{
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:green;
 float:left;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.blankStyle{
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:orange;
 float:left;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.fixer{
 width:100%;
 height:10px;
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<body>

<button onclick="checkPlayerChoice()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p> lives: </p>
<p id = "lives"> 0</p>
<p> Score: </p>
<p id = "scoreTotal">0</p>
<p>wins</p>
<p id ="winTotals">0</p>
<p>losses</p>
<p id ="lossTotals">0</p>
<p id ="gameOver"></p>

<button onclick ="resetGame()">New Game</button>

<p>Here is the word</p>
<p id = "wordDisplayer">Press New Game to Start</p>
<div id = "wordTiles"></div>
<div class ="fixer"></div>

<button onclick ="checkPlayerGuess()">What Key was Pressed?</button>
<p id ="isThisWorking">What will I say?</p>

<p>Letters Still Available</p>
<p id ="lettersStillAvailable"></p>
<p>Bad Guesses</p>
<p id ="lettersUsed"></p>

<br />
```

```js
selectedWord ="food";
function checkPlayerChoiceNew(){
 var splitWord = selectedWord.split("");
 var choice = new RegExp(playerGuess);
 var compareWord = choice.test(selectedWord.toLowerCase());
 var compareAlphabet = choice.test(remainingLetters);
 var compareRemovedList = choice.test(removedLetters);
 
 for (m = 0; m < splitWord.length; m++){
  //alert(splitWord[m]);
  if(playerGuess == splitWord[m]){
   document.getElementById(splitWord[m]).innerHTML = choice;
 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your Reg Expression `playerGuess`.

Comment: Its a global variable that holds the letter the user enters by pressing a key. I didnt post the whole script because its over 200 lines. Would it help if I did?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this below logic. In this example, I have given some inputs.

```js
var selectedWord ="food";
var displayString = [];
for(var i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++){
  displayString[i] = "-"
}
var outputEle = document.getElementById("output");
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = displayString.join(" ");
outputEle.appendChild(div);
function checkPlayerChoiceNew(playerGuess){
  var newWord = "";
  var regExp = new RegExp(playerGuess,'ig')
 selectedWord.replace(regExp, function(value, index){  
    displayString[index] = value;
    return value;  
  });
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = displayString.join(" ");
  outputEle.appendChild(div);
  newWord = displayString.join("");
  if(selectedWord == newWord){ alert("You Won the game"); }
  //outputEle.innerText = displayString.join(" ");  
}
checkPlayerChoiceNew('o');
checkPlayerChoiceNew('g');
checkPlayerChoiceNew('d');
checkPlayerChoiceNew('f');
```

```html
<div id="output">
  
</div>
```